# When is the "post_save" signal in django activated/called?

Tags: python, django

I've to update some database tables after saving a particular model. I've used the `@receiver(post_save` decorator for this. But when in this decorator function, the values are still not saved in the database. I've one to many relation but when I get the current instance that is being saved using `kwargs['instance']`, it doesn't have child objects. But after saving when I check from shell, it does have child objects. Following is the code that I'm using:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Test)
def do_something(sender, **kwargs):
    test = kwargs['instance']
    users = User.objects.filter(tags__in=test.tags.values_list('id',flat=True))
    for user in users:
        other_model = OtherModel(user=user, test=test, is_new=True)
        other_model.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

post_save is sent at the end of Model.save_base(), which is itself called by Model.save((). This means that if you override your model's save() method, post_save is sent when you call on super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kw).

If Tag has a ForeignKey on Test and the Test instance was just created, you can't expect to have any Tag instance related to your Test instance at this stage, since the Tag instances obviously need to know the Test instance's pk first so they can be saved too.

Comment: So how can and where can I write the code so the tags are set for the Test instance?

Comment: @wasimbhalli: Depends on where you set the tags.

Answer (score 0):

The post_save for the parent instance is called when the parent instance is saved. If the children are added after that, then they won't exist at the time the parent post_save is called.

Comment: I've used a breakpoint in post_save function. I stop the code there and see if the entry is saved. But, it's not saved at that time. I'm in the 'post_save' so it should have been saved?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. The entry is saved, but the children are not.

Comment: ok. So how do I execute my code AFTER the children are saved? I've used `models.ManyToManyField` for the relationship.

Comment: What about [m2m_changed](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) then?